# JavaScript Namespace/scope issue

Tags: leaflet, jquery

Ok, using Leaflet, JQuery GeoJSON layers, and JavaScript.

I have a simple map with an HTML checkbox, that should turn on a Leaflet layer. The html input has an onClick function that it passes a layer name to.

I use JQuery $.getJSON to read the GeoJSON data. with the layers defined inside the getJSON function. I need to place the updateLayerVis outside this function so the html part can see it. However now I can't use layerName.addTo(map); as layerName is now undefined.

I've looked at JavaScript namespace examples, and basically it's call the outsidefunction.insidefunction() but how do you do this with $.getJSON to get the layers?  Is there a better way? My code simplified.

```
<input id="larynx_chk" type="checkbox" class="list_item" onClick='updateLayerVis("larynx");'/>

var larynx;

function style(feature) {
    return {
        -----
    };
}

function theOnEachFeature(feature, layer){
    -----
}

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    larynx = new L.GeoJSON(data,{ 
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: theOnEachFeature, 
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
        return feature.properties.CANCERTYPE =="larynx";}
    });

    larynx.addTo(map); // will turn layer on.
});

function updateLayerVis(layer){
    ----

    larynx.addTo(map);  // fails larynx undefined.
}
```

Comment: you may have a typo on line 3, where you define larynZ rather than larynX.

Comment: notwithstanding that, you could use the [Layer Control](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#control-layers) to toggle the layer on/off

Comment: The Layer Control is not really an option. I'm replacing a mash up of Java, Google, ArcGIS map with Leaflet and I need to replicate the look they have in the old app.  Thanks for the editing, I was having trouble with the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I thought it was a scope issue, after working on it I found it was a string vs. layer issue. While I had the layer name as a string and passed it to my updateLayerVis function, the function received a string value not the layer, the quick fix was a switch statement for my 15 layers.

```
function updateLayerVis(a){
  // a.addTo(map);  // a.addTo is not a function

  switch(a) {
    case ("larynx"):
        larynx.addTo(map);
        break;
    case ("oral"):
        oral.addTo(map);
        break;
  }
}
```

If you know a better way please let me know for next time. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a namespace/scope issue. This is an **asynchronicity** issue. `larynx` has a value of `undefined` until some (potentially very slow) network operation has finished, so any operations on `larynx` before it's initialized will fail.

The variable scopes look good. You need `larynx` to be accessible from several parts of the code, so you've put it in the scope that is common to all the parts that need a reference to it. That's a sane thing to do.

It's common for a beginner-intermediate JS programmer to have trouble with JS doing asynchronous things. How to overcome issues related to async initialization?

#### Add sanity checks

Whenever you handle a variable that is potentially not initialized, do a sanity check, to see if it's in fact initialized. e.g.:

```
function updateLayerVis(layer){
    if (larynx !== undefined) {
        larynx.addTo(map);
    }
}
```

#### Do not let the user do things before it's time to do things

In other words: do not let the user activate the visibility of `larynx` until it has been loaded. e.g. something like:

```
<input id="larynx_chk" type="checkbox" disabled />

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    ...

    larynx.addTo(map);
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('larynx_chk');
    checkbox.disabled = false;
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', function(){ updateLayerVis('larynx')});
}
```

That way, the user will not be able to click on that checkbox until the data has been loaded. Makes sense, right?

---

I'm sure there are more ways to work around your specific problem. But it's more important that you understand the *concept* of "do not let your code assume that things are in a ready state".

Comment: Well you answer was helpful but not the right answer. Now if I pass the function the parameter which is the layer name, it doesn't work unless the layer name is hard coded.                                                                              function updateLayerVis(a){
  console.log(a);  // Shows larynx
  a.addTo(map);  // fails     a.addTo is not a function
  larynx.addTo(map);  //works
 };

Comment: Sounds like a variable scope issue. [Read up about javascript closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing the approach slightly, by defining the larynx layer and populating it on map instantiation - this way, you only need to run one AJAX query to retrieve the records. Then toggle its visibility using the checkbox:

Within your HTML:

`<label><input id="larynx_chk" type="checkbox">Toggle larynx layer</label`>

Within your JS:

```
// Define the empty larynx layer
var larynx = new L.GeoJSON(null,{ 
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: theOnEachFeature, 
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
        return feature.properties.CANCERTYPE =="larynx";
    }
});

// Populate the larynx layer with the data retrieved via AJAX
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    larynx.addData(data);
});

// Toggle the layer on/off using the checkbox and a jQuery listener
$("#larynx_chk").on("click", function(){
    if(larynx._map == undefined || larynx._map == null) {
        larynx.addTo(map);
    } else {
        map.removeLayer(larynx);
    }
})
```

Comment: Steven, I tried your suggestion while it worked with 15 layers I had 15 separate on click events. I liked your example..